# Error Directory index forbidden by Options directive:

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd

Qlguien podría ayudarme con el siguiente error me aparece cuando alguien intenta accesar a ciertos link de mi sitio:

> Directory index forbidden by Options directive:

Aquí mi configuración de Apache en Centos 7. Uso un host virtual:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName servidor.midominio.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/servidor/public_html

    <Directory /var/www/servidor/public_html/>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/www/editor/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/editor/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intente esto y reinicie el servicio de apache.

```
<Directory /var/www/servidor/public_html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks #se quita el -
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve el mismo problema, intenté varias cosas que leí en varios partes de ayuda y todos apuntaban a lo mismo: que si más, que si menos, que si FollowSymLinks... todos apuntando a modificar el httpd.conf.

Supongo que el problema en mi caso fue con la instalación en el opensuse porque en el lubuntu no había tenido problema haciendo páginas para la intranet. Supongo que mi problema es tratar de instalar las cosas igual que como se hace en lubuntu.

Instalé Apache y esas cosas desde la consola pero.... bueno para no dar tantas vueltas por las ramas lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

1. En opensuse abres el yast,
2. das click en "instalar desinstalar software",
3. click en ver,
4. click en patrones,
5. click en "servidor web y LAMP", y
6. desinstalas todo lo que está en este apartado (dependencias y todo),
7. reinstalas el yast. En la consola ejecutas

   ```
   zypper install yast2*"
   ```

   (el asterisco es muy importante) y le das al traste a las dependencias, e
8. instalas Python,
9. después reinicias, y
10. abres el YaST
11. click en "instalar desinstalar software",
12. luego en ver,
13. click en patrones,
14. luego palomeas  "Servidor web y LAMP"
15. y click en aceptar.

A mí me ha funcionado de esta forma, espero les sea útil, al final la configuración queda con un none. Tal vez no resuelva todo el problema pero creo yo que en mi caso es un problema con el instalador, mas concretamente sospecho que es un problema con el yast, por eso mejor lo reinstale y me quede con problemas de dependencias que ya luego me daran dolor de cabeza.